# iOS - FCModel - Error when save model when not passing the null values

Tags: ios, fmdb

I am using [FCModel](https://github.com/marcoarment/FCModel) for maintaining db on iOS app. It is producing NSUnknownKeyException when I try to save a model object without passing any value or nil value and save the object.

This is my Customer model interface:

```
@interface Customer : FCModel
    @property (nonatomic) int64_t id;
    @property (nonatomic) NSNumber *age;
    @property (nonatomic) NSString *profession;
    @property (nonatomic) NSString *first_name;
    @property (nonatomic) NSString *last_name;
@end
```

Create table statements:

```
if (! [db executeUpdate:
     @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CUSTOMER ("
         @"id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"// 0: id
         @"age INTEGER," // 1: server_id
         @"'profession' TEXT," // 2: c_id
         @"'first_name' TEXT," // 3: first_name
         @"'last_name' TEXT);" // 4: last_name
     ]) failedAt(1);
```

And this is the initialisation and saving part:

```
Customer *customer = [Customer new];
[customer initWithNil];
customer.first_name = @"first_name";
customer.last_name = @"last_name";
[customer save];
```

I am not able to figure out why it is giving NSUnknownKeyException for null allowed columns. I tried passing them as nil as well but that is also not working.

EDIT: I added a log in FCModel encodedValueForFieldName method and found that the fieldName is coming as null. Not sure if that is correct behaviour.

Comment: Are you sure the columns are allowed to be empty?

Comment: Yes. By default sqlite3 add column with null value unless you specify a not null constraint.

Answer (score 1):

It's been about a year since this question was brought up, but could it be that the create statement was incomplete? Removing the Objective-C and comments leaves you with:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CUSTOMER (
     id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
     age INTEGER,
     'profession' TEXT,
     'first_name' TEXT,
     'last_name' TEXT,
```

Perhaps you meant to close it off at the end.

```
'last_name' TEXT);
```

Comment: It was not the issue. It was just the typo in the question.

Comment: Okay. I figured, but I wanted to be sure. How did you go about resolving the situation? I'm seeing this issue now, too.

Comment: Actually, I see what the issue was. I'll add a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into FCModel and testing it myself, I came across the same issue. The problem is the name of your class and the name of the database table. They need to be the same. The easy solution is to change your database create to have the proper case.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Customer (
```

This should correct this issue.

The reason for the error is that FCModel is trying to find information for the wrong table. During the first pass, it is trying to find the primary key. The table it's looking for is "Customer" but you had created it as "CUSTOMER". Because it couldn't find the table, it was returning null.